# Unable to connect from one Windows machine to another

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

A friend of mine has two machines, both running Windows 7, both on the same network, both in a WORKGROUP. He wants to be able to connect to a network share on machine A from machine B, and I told him it would be easy :S

Both machines have identical user names with identical passwords. When I attempt to connect to machine B from machine A using the existing user credentials, it fails to authenticate. I tried disabling the firewalls on both machines and it still failed.

When I had exhausted my networking knowledge (i.e. after a few minutes), I added a completely new user on both machines. Using the new user, *everything worked fine*.

So it seems there's something wrong with the existing user accounts that is confusing Windows...? After asking my friend questions, I discovered that the user accounts in question were not created from scratch on both machines. e.g. Machine A originally had "foo" as the user name and machine B had "bar". Both were renamed to "user".

Can anyone tell me how to fix or diagnose this further? My recourse is to simply create a separate "admin" account on both machines and have him use that, but it's clunky and I'd like to understand why things aren't working as is.

Comment: Did you try adding just one New user to one of the computers, it would then have a different ID ?  I donno but you cant connect computer A to computer A :-)  they both need different ID number things so the magic can happen, if a users ID number is exactally the same as a user who is already logged-in , how would that work?  Usually these IDs are different, even with the same name, different numbers got assigend to them, so the system must be a clone or something?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the other machine when it prompts you for credentials enter

Machinename\username (with machine name being the name you are connecting to). This will then authenticate you as the local user on the destination computer.

Also have you setup your network share, as a test right click on the folder you want to share and goto properties.  Goto sharing and choose share.

Make the share available to everyone initially so that you can prove access without authentication.

If this works you can look to lock down access by adjusting the permissions from within the same menu.